# Get wrong URL ending

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'd like to be able to track what my website visitors do wrong when they enter a faulty URL on my website. I'd like the end string to be uploaded into my database, for example:

Correct URL: *https://www.example.com/example*

Wrong URL entered: *https://www.example.com/exmaple*

I know how to get the URL ending from an existing part of the site and upload it to my database, but how do I get the erroneous URL ending (*exmaple* in this case) from a part of the site that doesn't exist in a usable format for the purpose (stored in a PHP variable for instance)?

Comment: Setup your server to serve a 404 page

Comment: @WaisKamal Maybe, but I can't see this person trying to store the ending as a variable. I might just be too stupid to get it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes the redirect alone is easy enough, but keeping the erroneous URL ending and storing it in a variable on the 404 page is what I don't get how to do

Comment: Not sure it works, but try calling `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` from the page you redirect to.

Comment: @WaisKamal Misunderstood how the .htaccess redirect worked, since it doesn't seem to redirect to 404.php at all but just include it somehow, so `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` worked fine aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the information about what your clients have asked for is in the server access log.

For Debian/Ubuntu flavours of Linux these log files are in `/var/log/apache2`. The location may vary in other flavours of Linux, and Windows will differ too.

Here's a sample from Apache 2.4 for an absent file called `fred`. I've highlighted the 404 response code

> 192.168.237.28 - - [24/Jan/2021:09:57:56 +1300] "GET /fred HTTP/1.1" `404` 497 "-"
> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0
> "

Read the file, search for the statuses you want, add the data to a database, print a report, whatever.